# My computer randomly switches off

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

Well my computer is about 2 years old and recently it began turning off sporadically so my first thought was to open the case and look for any dust, no dust was found but i realised that the CPU cooler fan was not working. Surfed through amazon and purchased a Arctic cooler and installed it. After 3/4 hours of medium intensity gaming the pc switched off again (needless to say I was dissapointed). I went and did some reading and could it be my power pack not having enough power or being faulty?

The image is just while using the computer to watch Youtube etc.

[image: load]

Comment: Sounds like a power supply issue. Does it only turn off when it's under moderate to heavy load? It could be possible that the CPU is overheating though, but I think there is a screen associated with that shutdown. I'm not 100℅ sure though

Comment: Need more information. CPU, Motherboard, Power Supply ratings.  Some boards don't issue a warning for heat, they just shut down and  you may have options in the bios to allow higher CPU temperatures before shutdown (for testing). Depending on the board manufacturer, they may have a utility to install to watch the CPU temps. My previous machine did similar after 2 ~ 3 years, it wasn't until I pulled the system out for inspection that I found the plastic anchor the heatsink attaches to had broken and the heatsink no longer had good contact to the CPU (zip-ties went to the rescue!) :-)

Comment: What is the room temperature?

Comment: CPU Type
AMD FX(tm)-6350 Six-Core Processor
Core Clock
975 MHz
Graphics Chipset
AMD Radeon (TM) R9 200 Series
AMD 3+

Comment: 500 watt power supply, Room temp is roughly 18 degrees Celsius, yes the computer turns off if i use it for prolonged periods of time, 5/6 hours under moderate load and 2/3 hours under heavy load.
Hope thats enough information

Comment: When you installed the artic cooler, did you apply new thermal paste?

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU temp hit 78.9c.  The highest temp for your CPU is 70c.  This is MAX.  It should never hit this.  I noticed one of the temp on the motherboard sensor hit 90c!  This is likely the one under the CPU socket.  It is highly likely that your CPU has been damaged because the fan stopped working.  Change the CPU.

When reinstalling the heat sink and fan, be sure to use a generous amount of high quality thermal paste.  Buy Arctic Silver if you can afford it.  They are about $6 for a small tube.  Make sure you install the brackets correctly, and make sure the heat sink is flat against the CPU.

Download "Core Temp" and it will monitor your CPU temp constantly and it can give you a warning notification when a certain temp is reached.